# I can't deploy using sshagent

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, ssh-agent

im learning jenkins for the moment and i had a problem with sshagent . i can't connect to my remote machine .
first i'm trying to deploy into kubernetes using jenkins .and i'm using ssh agent to get into kubernetes-master so i can run command from it .
so the probleme is i genareted a ssh key in my kubernetes-master and i added   the private key to jenkins but it not working .
any help here plz
here you find  the stage .of deployment in the pipeline
and the output console when i executed the job
[jenkins output  console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2RWJ.jpg)

```
 stage('deploy to K8s cluster '){
        steps{
             sshagent(['Jenkins-Access-Kube']) {
                         sh"scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  /home/automate-deployment-on-k8s/complete-demo.yaml younes@192.168.8.199:/home/younes/k8s"
                script{
                  try{
                        sh 'ssh younes@192.168.8.199  kubectl apply -f . '
                  }catch(error){
                        sh 'ssh younes@192.168.8.199 kubectl create -f . '
                  }
                }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting 700 to .ssh and 600 to authorized_keys solved the issue.

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: wondering, how do you know it solv**ed**the issue? :)

Comment: your Jenkins output shows a permission denied error, which is related to file permission. just try to update the permission. and check again.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to `scp` through the user `younes`. In the `scp` command he has not used `-i </path/to/the/private/key>`  that caused the `permission denied`.  Based on the logs, the private keys are copied to `/var/lib/jenkins` but he did not provide it `scp`.

Comment: Also, the error for permissions(`group/world readable`) would generate different errors(feel free to reproduce in your machine). Not the error shown In the logs.  So, **perhaps the answer is not correct.** . (happy to be corrected)